# Vestal_versions : List all the versions of the edit in the rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version

i am using vestal_version in my rails app. And i am wondering how do I show the previous versions edit links with respect to what is at the above entry. My html.erb code is

```
        <tbody>
                        <% @page.versions.each do |page| %>
                        <tr class="odd">
                          <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                          <td> </td>
                          <td><%= page.created_at%></td>
                          <td>
                          <% if params[:version] %>
                          <%= link_to "Previous Version", :version => @page.version-1 %>
                          <%end%>
                        </td>
                        </tr>


                  </div>
         <% end %>
```

and in controller i have `@page.revert_to(params[:version].to_i) if params[:version]`

I have attached a link to the screenshot. And if closely observe. the ?version=5 for all the entries. I want to have all the versions that is 1,2,3,4 and 5. How do i do that ?

Update : Image is hyper linked in the comment. I am not allowed add an image as of now.

Comment: [Image is here](http://uploadpic.org/storage/2011/oFUWvPJF0u0vqQwpXaWHySLo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `page` instead of `@page`.

```
<%= link_to "Previous Version", :version => page %>
```

`page` changes with each iteration, while `@page` stays the same.

**EDIT:**

Since `@page.versions.each` iterates a collection of versions, it should be passed into the block as `version`, not `page`.

```
<% @page.versions.each do |version| %>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td><%= version.created_at%></td>
    <td>
    <%= link_to "Show Version", :version => version %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This method only shows the version. Actually reverting a version should be done via POST, since you are making changes to the database.

Reverting negates changes, it does not discard changes. If `page` is at version 4, and you revert to version 2, it does not delete versions 3 and 4. The version *number* will revert to 2, but will count as a version itself.

`#revert_to` does the reversion but does not save. To revert *and* save, use `#revert_to!`

---

To properly use `#revert_to!`, you need to put it in a **controller action**.

Example, in your `pages` controller:

```
def revert
  @page = Page.find params[:id]
  if @page.revert_to!(params[:version_id]) # <= revert_to!
    redirect_to @page
  else
    render :text => "Did not revert"
  end
end
```

In your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :pages do
  member do
    post 'revert_to/:version_id' => 'pages#revert', :as => :revert
  end
end
```

then in your view:

```
<% @page.versions.each do |version| %>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td> </td>
    <td><%= version.created_at %></td>
    <td>
    <%= link_to "Show Version", :version => version %>
    </td>
    <td>
    <%= button_to "Revert to this version", revert_page_path(@page, version.id) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Its gives an `undefined method 'version' for #<VestalVersions::Version:0xb2de9984>` error. Also how do I save the undo or reverts ? because when i go to /pages/2 the changes dont take effect

Comment: well having just `:version => page` solves the purpose. Though i might need to twea the first edit which is displayd. Since, thats unnecessary or may be not. I will see. But now how i do save the version edits ?

Comment: can you please help me with this question ?

Comment: okay yes i understand this. but then how do i revert the changes and save them. i am assuming its a completely different method. can you please help me with that as well ? thank you so much.

Comment: Answer revised again... it's `#revert_to!`

Comment: i tried :revert_to! => version . because #comments out or am i suppose to enter it somehwere else ? And :revert_to! => version doesnt do anything either..it does not change back

Comment: I really appreciate all your help.thanks. can you help me out on this as well ? :)

Comment: Say I want to revert to version 2: `#revert_to!(2)`  Read the documentation in source code to see how it works: https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions/blob/master/lib/vestal_versions/reversion.rb#L13

Comment: yes, so i got this in my show.html.erb `<td><%= link_to "Show version", :revert_to! => version %></td>` . but then its not working. And yes i went through the doc. Are you suggesting that i should have the commands in the controller rather than having then in .html.erb ? And also do i need to declare a POST method separately ? Or revert_to! does that ? Thanks so much again :)

Comment: any help on this again please ? :)

Comment: Correct. The commands should be in a controller. And yes, a POST should be used. See my (final) revised answer.

Comment: thanks. one last help ? i am getting `undefined method 'revert_page_path'` ..am i missing something?

Comment: Restart your server to load in the new route.

Comment: Make sure `resources :pages` is not defined twice in your routes. If that doesn't solve it, you must do you your own troubleshooting from here. We cannot continue generating a lengthy comment thread.